# Add options to the "Screen Options" section on the "Menus" editor

Tags: customization, filters, screen-options

I'm working on a system to add custom options to the WordPress menu editor, and I'd like to integrate it with the Screen Options panel. In my research, I couldn't find anything on modifying an existing screen options menu; is this possible? See the screenshots below to better understand what I'm trying to accomplish.

Default "Screen Options" on Appearance > Menus:

[image: default]

Goal "Screen Options" on Appearance > Menus:

[image: custom]

Comment: Aren't you looking for the [`add_screen_option`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_screen_option) hook?

Comment: I did see that, but it didn't seem to be working. I'll give it another try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out by looking through the WordPress source code

```
function new_site_add_custom_screen_options($args) {
    $args["custom_option_1"] = __("Custom Option 1", "new_site");
    $args["custom_option_2"] = __("Custom Option 2", "new_site");

    return $args;
}
add_filter("manage_nav-menus_columns", "new_site_add_custom_screen_options", 20);
```

Comment: The format of the filter is `add_filter("manage_{$screen->id}_columns"`. It's easy to get the screen id with the plugin Query Monitor .